# Rendering custom sections of an ASP.NET MVC EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am late in on a project where possibly the most important requirements have been ignored until the 11th hour.

The application allows suppliers to apply to become contractors for a company via a fairly in depth online application form.

The application takes the form of question sections that make up a left sidebar nav and each section has a number of questions.

The requirements that have been ignored up until now are that each applicant who fills out a form online has an application type, e.g. construction, catering etc. and the requirements state that the application is configurable so that only certain sections appear to a certain application type and certain questions within a section should be configurable to appear to a particular application type.

Configuring the sections is easy but configuring the questions is not so easy.  At the moment everything is hardcoded into razor views and `EditorFor` templates.  Basically there is one `EditorFor` per ViewModel which makes up a Section e.g.

```
@model Models.Enforcement
<div >
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="@Url.Action(nameof(ApplicationController.Enforcements))"
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x)
        </div>
```

And the editor for will look something like this:

```
    @model GSCM.Logic.Web.Models.Enforcement
    @using System.Web.Mvc.Html

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

My solution to this problem is to first of all be able to add custom attributes to a ViewModel class that tag the property as a configurable Question, e.g.

```
public class Enforcement
{
  [ApplicationQuestion DisplayOrder=1, Partial="DifferentNamedPartial"]
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I then have my own `EditorFor` that loops through all these tagged Properties:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString QuestionSetEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, VMBaseClass model)
    {
        //PSEUDO CODE
        var sectionHtml;

        ForEach(var taggedProperty in model)
        {
           var basedOnProperty = GetFilePathFromProperty(taggedProperty);
           sectionHtml += System.Web.Mvc.Html.GetPartial(basedOnProperty)
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sectionHtml);
    }

}
```

So basically, I would need to chop up the existing EditorFor ViewModel templates and have a partial for each section, property.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea or is there a better way.  Time is a constraint (as always)?
2. Can I create the html string in the way I have outlined above with the pseduo code that loops rounds the properties and calls out to the partials?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can proceed like

Suppose  your partial pages which you want to call in main pages using loops are:

```
_form-one-partial.cshtml
_form-two-partial.cshtml
_form-three-partial.cshtml
_form-four-partial.cshtml
_form-five-partial.cshtml
```

One of those partial page content as:

```
@model PartialFieldViewModel

//---other fileds on the page
 <input type="text"/>
//---other fileds on the page
```

To call the partial on the basis of the loop around the "partial" varible in the main page where partial will be called as:

```
@model PartialViewModel



 foreach (var partial in Model.Parital)
    {
     @Html.Partial("_form-{0}-partial".FormatWith(partial.PartialType.ToString().ToLower()), partial)
   }
```

Partial view modal class as

```
 public class PartialViewModel
    {
        //Other properties
        public List<PartialFieldViewModel> Partial { get; set; }

    }



  public class PartialFieldViewModel
    {     
            //Other properties 
            public Constants.PartialType PartialType{ get; set; }       
    }
```